# Pride Flags and the First Amendment

Tags: first-amendment

The city of Hamtrack, MI prohibits on government property any flags "displaying sexual orientation, as well as other religious, ethnic, racial and political flags". The ban was enacted during Pride month after the Pride flag was raised on city property, and it is widely understood that the ban was aimed at Pride flags.

However, would this prevent someone from bringing their own Pride flag onto city public property?

Cf. Gray v. Lt. Hemminger: A man brought a sign onto publicly accessible property owned by the city and was asked to leave due to the content of the sign, probably by a city employee who was unfamiliar with First Amendment protections. https://www.thefire.org/gray_v_Port_Wentworth_Complaint

Comment: Does it ban them from being present on government (public) property, or ban the government from displaying them?  Those are two very different things.  A full quote, or a link would be helpful.

Comment: In what sense is the US flag not a political flag? A certain sector of the population sure likes to use it as one. Feels like there's lots of vectors for attack on this one.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, nobody said anything about the US flag...

Comment: @MichaelHall The point is the statute seems rather broad.  It bans all political flags.  Which arguably includes state and national flags, as many use them as political emblems asserting they're the ones with the "true" faith, and any "bad" actions they take are those of "patriots" etc., and which are traditionally flown at state capitals and other government buildings.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, it does?  How about posting a link or quote then?

Comment: @MichaelHall [Try this one.](https://www.freep.com/story/news/local/michigan/wayne/2023/07/09/lgbtq-pride-flag-ban-hamtramck/70393216007/) It includes the line quoted by OP. I'm not having much luck just finding the text of the resolution, which isn't terribly surprising since this is a city level thing, but there's several articles you can find by going through links in that article that report on the matter's prior development.